# Presenting UIImagePickerController removes the NavigationBar on the current controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a tab bar application with several controllers. Some are `UINavigationControllers`, some just simple `UIViewControllers`.
The central button presents the `UIImagePickerController` to allow the user to take a picture.
When I present the Image Picker from a simple `UIViewControllers`, it works fine.
But when I present it while a `UINavigationController` is currently the `selectedViewController`, the dismall of the picker removes the `UINavigationBar` of the controller.

I read that with `UINavigationControllers`, the modal view must be presented from the `navigationController`, but it does not work either. 
Here are bunches of code :

```
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
    {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Erreur"
                                  message:@"Pour pouvoir poster des photos, votre device doit posséder un appareil photo"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
    }
    if ([self.selectedViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    {
        [self.selectedViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.selectedViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
```

the dismall :

```
[self.selectedViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Has anyone got this strange behavior (guess it has something to do with the fact that `UIImagePickerController` delegate must implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate`) and know how to resolve that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that when you dismiss the image picker, the navigation bar is no longer present? You should log self.selectedViewController to make sure you are presenting it from the controller you think you are.

Comment: That is what I meant. After dismissing the picker, I push a controller on the navigation stack and the navigation bar is hidden. I have to change to another tab and get back to the current controller to make it appear again. Really weird.

Comment: Do you see the navigation bar right after the modal view is dismissed but before you push the next controller?

Comment: it's the weirdest thing. I push a page, present the modal controller and dismiss the picker. The bar is here. I pop the page and push a new one. The bar is gone. I choose another tab entry and get back the current one. The bar is there again... Weirder and weirder...

Comment: So, what you have in your title is not actually what's happening -- it's not the presenting (or dismissal) of the image picker that's causing the problem, but the subsequent popping and pushing. You should edit your post and show the code where you do that. Also, describe anything you're doing in IB. Are you doing this all in code or using xibs or storyboards?

Comment: No it is happening because of the modal view presenting. Otherwise, the navigation controllers work just fine and as expected. It is the dismissal of the modal controller while a navigationController is set as the selectedController that creates this problem. This issue is described here too --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034033/presenting-a-modal-view-controller-hides-the-navigation-bar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20196/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-khal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to pickerController using this

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

And its **delegate** method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    NSData *dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],1);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Or**

Make sure that you are not setting any `setHidden` in your Code.

Comment: then what was the problem.. i don't think that after this you are getting problem... like dismiss only picker not the self.selectedViewController

Comment: It was actually really more simple : in the viewWillAppear, I set the hidden property to NO and in the viewWillDissapear I set it to YES.
The thing is : when the modal controller is presented, the viewWillDisappear was called. But when it was dismissed, the viewWillAppear was not called... Not really the expected behavior, but still. Thanks guys.

Comment: ya i was thinking that you are setting hidden someWhere because there is not any issue in your code....nice, your problem is solved now....i think i have to update my answer..congrts..:)

Answer (score 1):

It was actually really more simple : in the `viewWillAppear`, I set the hidden property to `NO` and in the `viewWillDisappear` I set it to `YES`. The thing is : when the modal controller is presented, the `viewWillDisappear` was called. But when it was dismissed, the `viewWillAppear` was not called... Not really the expected behavior, but still. Thanks guys.