# Present a modal view controller, but don't hide the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm modally presenting a viewController with a semi-transparent view. It's a custom activity indicator. I would like it to cover the view, but leave the navigation bar and tab bar visible and accessible.

The docs, and several SO answers (e.g. [Presenting a Modal View Controller hides the Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034033/presenting-a-modal-view-controller-hides-the-navigation-bar)) seem to suggest that presenting the modal onto the navigation controller should achieve this. But when I do it, it shows the tab bar correctly, but covers the navigation bar.

Any ideas? Here is the relevant code:

```
let spinnerVC = SpinnerViewController()
spinnerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
spinnerVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.navigationController?.present(spinnerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
//self.navigationController is definitely not nil
```

Answer (score 3):

You can present a your `viewcontroller` by adding as `rootViewController` of a `navigationController` and then present it over the current `viewController` like this:

```
let spinnerVC = SpinnerViewController()
let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:spinnerVC)
navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
navVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: That presents the spinner view with *a* navigation bar. But not the underlying one. To be clear, I would like the underlying navigation bar to be visible, complete with its title and buttons, so the user can navigate away if desired.

Comment: To show the underlying navigation bar, you can add spinnerVC as a child view controller with animation which resembles same as presenting a view controller

Answer (score 1):

you could do it two ways:
first one:

Put this code in your parent view

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

second one:
Add a reference to your invoker in your alert controller in order to hide the bar like this:

```
weak var invokerView : UIViewController?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.invokerView?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.invokerView?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't present it. Add it as a child view controller to the top view controller of your navigation controller and add its view as a subView to the view of the same adjusting the frame.

```
let spinnerVC = SpinnerViewController()
spinnerVC.view.frame = self.navigationController?.topViewController?.view.bounds
self.navigationController?.topViewController?.addChildViewController(spinnerVC)
self.navigationController?.topViewController?.view.addSubview(spinnerVC.view)
```

Comment: Yes, I considered this. But done this way, it requires additional work to ensure it behaves correctly (e.g. isn't scrollable, no further subviews get presented on top of it if the timing is wrong, etc). Because this is meant to be very flexible, and be presented on various views throughout my app, this wouldn't be ideal. Was hoping for a simple model presentation.

Comment: Modal presentation covers the whole context (which includes the nav bar of your vc). You can adjust the frame size to decrease the height but it will be black there instead of the nav bar as underlying content isn't visible.

Comment: You can do the above but by creating an extension to UIViewController to add a function that would do this for you so it can be reusable throughout your app.

Comment: By using modalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext, you can have a modal show content underneath it. (e.g. in my case, the modal's view is semi-transparent, so shows the underlying view). I've tried adjusting the frame, but it seems to be overridden when presented modally on the navigation controller.

Comment: And, yes, I will be setting it up using extensions or another approach to make it reusable. But that doesn't prevent it needing a lot of extra logic to behave correctly when presented over, say, scroll views, or table views, or views where another subview might be added subsequently, and would end up on top of the 'modal', if it's just added as a subview.